# Transitivity of the notion of regularity for local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian catenary local ring and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime in $R$.

> **Question:** Is it true that if $(R/\mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{m})$ and $(R_\mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{p})$ are both regular local rings then $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is also regular?

As I am assuming $R$ to be catenary we have $$\dim R_\mathfrak{p} + \dim R/\mathfrak{p}=\dim R$$
Hence, it would be enough to prove that
$$\dim_{k(\mathfrak{p})} \mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^2 + \dim_{k(\mathfrak{m})} \mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{m}^2)=\dim_{k(\mathfrak{m})} \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$$

I am interested in this because of its translation to algebraic geometry: If $X$ is an algebraic variety, $Y\subseteq X$ is an irreducible subvariety whose local ring is regular and $x\in Y$ is a regular point in $Y$, then $x$ is regular in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $R=k[[x,y]]/(xy)$; then $R$ is a dimension $1$ reduced complete local ring.  In particular, the localization at any minimal prime is regular.  For example, such a minimal prime is $\mathfrak{p}=(x)$, and concretely, $R_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong \operatorname{Frac}(k[[y]])$.  Furthermore, $R/xR \cong k[[y]]$ is also regular, but $R$ is evidently singular.

Update: For a normal counterexample, let $R=k[[x,y,z]]/(xz-y^2)$, which is isomorphic to the second Veronese subring $k[[x^2,xy,y^2]]$ of $k[[x,y]]$.  In particular, $R$ is a normal domain and is singular. Let $\mathfrak{p}=(x,y) \in R$.  Then $R/\mathfrak{p} \cong k[[z]]$ which is regular, and, as $R$ is normal, it satisfies Serre's condition $R_1$, so automatically $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is regular.  However, we can also check this by hand: localizing at $(x,y)$ makes $z$ a unit, so the equation $xz-y^2$ becomes a linear form. A similar example can be taken by starting on the graded side and localizing at the irrelevant maximal ideal.

Comment: +1, good answer, but these power series brackets are displaying awfully for me. Is there a reason you chose to make these spacing alterations over the usual $[[$ and $]]$ ?

Comment: Well, I'll certainly keep that trick in mind next time those brackets aren't displaying so well in a paper - I never thought of that particular workaround before. Good day!

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice example! (Just a nitpick, I think it should be $R_\mathfrak{p}\cong \mathrm{Frac}(k[[x]])$) Also, I think this example works as well if we use the polynomial ring instead of the power series ring (that is, changing $R$ with $(k[x,y]/(xy))_{(x,y)}$).

Comment: I will accept the answer in a little while but it would be nice if someone can comment in the case in which $R$ is a domain or even an integrally closed domain.

Comment: @nowheredense It's $R_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong \operatorname{Frac}(k[[y]])$ since localizing at $(x)$ inverts not $(x)$ but the complement of $(x)$ (of course $\operatorname{Frac}(k[[y]]) \cong \operatorname{Frac}(k[[x]])$ anyway). You are correct that the example works if the power series ring is replaced by the polynomial ring localized at the irrelevant ideal. I'll think about a normal counterexample.

Comment: @nowheredense Why don't ask the same question adding the integral domain and/or integrally closed condition(s)?

Comment: @user26857 I decided to post my original motivation for this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612936/geometric-interpretation-of-regular-non-closed-points).