# Geometric interpretation of regular non-closed points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a variety (say, integral scheme of finite type) over an algebraically closed field $k$. Consider an irreducible closed subset $Y\subseteq X$ and let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$. I would like to know if the following is true.

> **Question:** The point $\eta$ is regular (i.e, $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is a regular local ring) if and only if there is at least one closed point $x\in Y$ that is regular on $X$.

The *if* part of the question is true due to a theorem of Serre: The localization of a regular local ring is a regular local ring. Because, if the variety $Y$ is defined by the prime ideal $P$ inside an affine chart containing $x$, then $(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})_{P\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}=\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$.

So I am interested in the *only if* part.

Notice that any algebraic variety has at least one regular closed point (cf. the book of Liu, section 4.2 Lemma 2.21, where it is proved over any field under the assumption of $X$ being geometrically reduced). Hence, $Y$ has at least one closed point $x$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,x}$ is regular. As we are assuming that $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is regular as well maybe some kind of *transitivity* of the regular property (in the sense of [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612093/transitivity-of-the-notion-of-regularity-for-local-rings) question that I asked before) would imply that the point $x$ is regular in $X$. Maybe the fact that the set of regular points in $Y$ is actually an open set (cf. Liu section 4.2 proposition 2.24) can be used to change the point $x$ in case some of them fails.

If you find a nice proof of this it would be nice to clean the unnecessary hypothesis as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what is going on is point-set topology, because of the following:

**Lemma.** *Let $X$ be a Jacobson space and consider a locally quasi-constructible subset $U \subseteq X$. If $Y \subseteq X$ is a locally quasi-constructible subspace such that $U \cap Y \ne \emptyset$, then there exists a point $x \in Y$ that is closed in $X$ such that $x \in U$.*

*Proof.* The set $U \cap Y$ is locally quasi-constructible in $Y$ by definition of the subspace topology, and is non-empty by hypothesis. Since $Y$ is a Jacobson topological space [[EGAI$_{\text{new}}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3075000), Chapitre 0, Proposition 2.8.2], we see that $U \cap Y$ contains a closed point $x \in Y$ by definition of a Jacobson space [[EGAI$_{\text{new}}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3075000), Chapitre 0, Définition 2.8.1]. This point $x$ is closed in $X$ by [[EGAI$_{\text{new}}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3075000), Chapitre 0, Proposition 2.8.2]. $\blacksquare$

To apply this to your situation, every scheme of finite type over a field $k$ is Jacobson [[EGAI$_{\text{new}}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3075000), Proposition 6.5.2], and setting $U$ to be the regular locus $\operatorname{Reg}(X)$, we see that $\operatorname{Reg}(X)$ is open, hence locally quasi-constructible.

Of course, maybe it is easier to just prove your statement directly: The set $\operatorname{Reg}(X) \cap Y$ is open in $Y$ by definition of the subspace topology, and is non-empty since it contains $\eta$. Since closed points are dense in $Y$ [[EGAI$_{\text{new}}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3075000), Proposition 6.5.2], there exists a point $x \in \operatorname{Reg}(X) \cap Y$ that is closed in $Y$. Finally, this point $x$ is closed in $X$ since $\{x\} \hookrightarrow Y \hookrightarrow X$ is a composition of closed embeddings.

Comment: Thanks!! this point of view really clarify things a lot. So, if we like generality we can conclude that my question is true on any scheme that is Jacobson and [J-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-2_ring), it may fail for example in the spectrum of local rings because these are far from being Jacobson.

Comment: Bravo, Takumi:+1

Comment: @nowheredense Yes, although you probably want to assume the scheme is locally noetherian for J-1 to make sense. I think the local case is false: take the local ring of a normal isolated surface singularity, and let $Y$ be a Weil divisor. And thank you very much, @GeorgesElencwajg!

Comment: Dear Takumi, I have written down, for future reference, a self contained statement resulting from the OP's question and your beautiful answer. I have also given a detailed one dimensional counter-example in the local case, in the spirit of your comment above.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of future reference let me spell out a version of Takumi's result and indicate why it may fail in a different context.
**Takumi's result**
Let $X$ be a scheme locally of finite type over a field $k$ or over $\mathbb Z$, let $\operatorname {Reg }(X)\subset X$ be the set of regular points and let $\operatorname {Reg }^{cl}(X)\subset \operatorname {Reg }(X)$ the set of *closed* regular points.
Then for any point $\eta\in X$ we have the equivalence: 
$$\boxed {\mathcal O_{X,\eta} \operatorname {is a regular local ring} \iff
\overline {\{\eta\}}\cap  \operatorname {Reg }^{cl}(X)\neq \emptyset  }$$ However the result is no longer true for arbitrary schemes:
**A very simple counter-example**
Let $k[x,y]=\frac {k[X,Y]}{\langle X\cdot Y\rangle}, \mathfrak m={\langle x, y\rangle}$ and $A=k[x,y]_\mathfrak m$, a singular local ring of dimension one.
Our counter-example concerns the scheme $X=\operatorname {Spec}A=\{ M,\eta, \xi\}$, where $M$ is the closed point corresponding to $\mathfrak m$ and  $\eta =\langle  y\rangle, \xi=\langle  x\rangle$ are the two open points of $X$.
We have $\operatorname {Reg }^{cl}(X)=\emptyset$, and so *a fortiori* $\overline {\{\eta\}}\cap \operatorname {Reg }^{cl}(X)= \emptyset  $.
However $\mathcal O_{X,\eta}$ is a regular local ring since it is the rational function field $k(x)$.
This counter-example is only possible because $A_\mathfrak m$ is not of finite type over $k$, and Takumi's assumption is thus not satisfied.
**An even simpler counter-example**
Let $k[x,y]=\frac {k[X,Y]}{\langle Y^2-X^3\rangle}, \mathfrak m={\langle x, y\rangle}$ and $A=k[x,y]_\mathfrak m$, a singular local ring of dimension one.
Our counter-example concerns the scheme $X=\operatorname {Spec}A=\{ M,\eta\}$, where $M$ is the closed point corresponding to $\mathfrak m$ and  $\eta =\langle  0\rangle$ is the  generic point of $X$, which is open.
We have $\operatorname {Reg }^{cl}(X)=\emptyset$, since the only closed point $M$ of $X$ is singular.
So *a fortiori* $\overline {\{\eta\}}\cap \operatorname {Reg }^{cl}(X)= \emptyset  $.
However $\mathcal O_{X,\eta}$ is a regular local ring since it is the field $k(x,y)=\operatorname {Frac}A=\operatorname {Frac}k[x,y]$.
Hence the boxed equivalence fails, and the reason again is that $X$ is not locally of finite type over $k$.

Comment: Thank you writing out the equivalence clearly! The example is great as well. I think one can also get an integral domain example by taking the local ring of the nodal cubic at the origin, since this ring has the same completion as your ring.

Comment: Dear Takumi, it was a pleasure to try and give your beautiful result the maximal visibility. I have followed your suggestion and have given as a counter-eample a scheme with only two points. I have chosen the cusp over the node because its equation is shorter :-)

Comment: Dear Takumi, I would like to add to the answer that  the boxed equivalence is still true if $k$ is replaced by  $\mathbb Z$ (there are generalizations of course, but they seem less useful and more complicated to state). Do you agree?

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, Yes, I think that would be very helpful!

Comment: Done.  Your theorem looks even better now!